How to disable Firefox search when not typing on any input field?
I want to play https://vim-adventures.com/, but I can't use any key, as Firefox will automatically start searching for text, as if I press Ctrl + F. I know this is convenient for most case, but here I want to disable it. How to do that?

I had the same issue when installing Vimium-FF and since then I had to disable Search on typing
